# MDList row and callback

Tags: kivymd

I add_widget of OneLineListItem  in MDlist and link it with a table in SQLITe. How to call out a function that do what i want to do after pressing on a specific row in MDList. Is there any way to get the row pressed index to deal with i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after long three days. I just use intance.id in callback function.

```
 def callback(self,instance):
        m=instance.id
```

it determine the row and you can deal with it. You have to add id to the widget when you add it>